# How do I logout of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, logout

A bit of fun really, but it's not entirely obvious...

So how do I logout of Stack Overflow?

I have clicked on my profile link, the one with my picture, and there's nothing there. I checked all the menu options on the top bar and couldn't find it, I also scanned my Profile page and didn't see anything there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow: `StackExchange -> log out (next to chat)` or [log out link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout).

Here's an image to further help:
[image: How to logout of StackOverflow]

I agree, the log out link isn't the easiest thing to find.